# Why does enabling WEP still allow me to connect to my D-Link router without encryption?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have D-Link wireless router that I use for my home network.  Everyone in the range of my wireless network can reach the internet, as it is unencrypted.  I tried to set password on it, but nothing happens - and when you want connect to my wireless, it doesn't ask for password.

How can I solve this issue?

P.S: I set 192.168.1.1 and go to wireless tab and set WEP password and restart my router.

Comment: Also, don't use WEP, use WPA2

Comment: That is, unless you have a reason to use WEP only (I'm looking at you Nintendo DS... the DSi fixes that problem)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use WPA instead of WEP if the router supports it. Second, are you saving the settings before you restart the router?

Comment: sure I save it. I must said that when I use Wizard it work well but when I want set it manually it doesn't work.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA - associate your serverfault and superuser account to be able to take ownership of this question here.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have to "enable" wireless security in a drop down list or a checkbox, not just set a WEP password.

If you could give us a model number, we'd be happy to give a step-by-step answer. [This article](http://www.techduke.com/2007/05/18/how-to-encrypt-your-wireless-connection-on-d-link-wep-key/) may be able to provide more information as well